# How to forward declare a function within the same class?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

There is a class A having all the declarations and definitions are placed inside as shown below:

```
class A
{
  void f(); // forward declaration for a lengthy method
  ...
  void g()
  {
    f();    // call the above forward-declared method
  }
  void f()  // definition of a lengthy method
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I don't want to take f() out of the class header like A::f(), but just want to keep all the source within the class.
However, when I compile it, I get the following error:

```
error C2535: 'void A::f()': member function already defined or declared
note: see declaration of 'A::f'
```

Isn't there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't need to forward declare it.

Comment: Just remove the forward declaration.

Comment: You don't need to forward declare methods. Just use them.

Comment: Names of all members are available everywhere inside the class definition even if they occur after the point where they are used. There's no need for forward declarations.

Comment: You even have to remove the forward declarations. A class does those automatically.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to forward declare the member function. And you cannot both forward declare, and define a member function within the class definition - If you forward declare, then you must define the member function outside of the class definition.

Member function definitions are in a "complete class context", which means that they have access to all members of the class, even those declared after the function body.

As such, your example can be fixed by removing the first declaration of `f`.

Comment: Three main reasons I want to forward declare f are:
- it is very much internal and implementation detail so that I just want it to be placed at the very end part of the class
- it is very lengthy code and I don't want it to be seen at the beginning of the class
- I just want to keep all the class code within the class header

If I can forward declare it as I wish, these two issues are to be properly handled.

There is no way to get these goals?

Comment: @HaeRimLee Why not define the function outside of the class definition?

Comment: Because I want to keep all the code within the class itself.  Just like a '.h' file.

Comment: @HaeRimLee But why do you want that?

Comment: You can keep the code in the class header, but you have to remove the forward declarations. Or at least comment them out. Forward declarations are unnecessary and not allowed for classes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess while compiling the class ... a function declaration would be considered as a whole a function that doesn't need a definition at the moment at least till we finish the whole compilation process of a single class then the function get in the column of declared function that need to be declared, so when you declare and define in the same (class or struct) you would get a function  overloading error, Plus it makes nonsense to forward declare and define in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep the declaration in the same header file here is one approach:

```
class A
{
  void f(); // declaration for a (lengthy) method
  ...
  void g()
  {
    f();    // call the above method
  }
};

void A::f()  // definition of a lengthy method
{
  ...
}
```

That out-of-line definition of your lengthy method can be moved down in the header file, or if you decide move it to a source file.